# Are here any problems with MacPorts and Homebrew installed together?

Tags: mac, uninstall, homebrew, macports

Here's the problem: some days ago I installed macports on my MacBook Air because I needed some c++ libraries but for some reason I wasn't able to use them. Then I upgraded my Mac to Mojave and the day after that I installed home-brew because I wasn't aware that the two cannot coexist. It did work well, so I wanted to uninstall macports but It wasn't possible because I had upgraded from high Sierra to Mojave so I first need to migrate macports to use its commands (even to uninstall it). The matter is: today I read that it's no good to have both macports and home-brew installed, so I installed home-brew and almost all of its files because I couldn't uninstall macports for the reasons above. Have I compromised anything by having both them installed for one day or is it everything like before now that I've uninstalled home-brew?

Answer (score 0):

I would following the instructions to [uninstall macports](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) and then do the same for [brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/install). Once you're certain both are removed, you can choose to properly install homebrew.

Comment: The matter is that I cannot uninstall MacPorts until the upgrade to Mojave is released, so I uninstalled homebrew and when the upgrade is available I will uninstall macports and reinstall homebrew